# Why are in R the names not passed along by list(x, y, z)?

Tags: r

By default, R creates an unnamed list:

```
x <- 42
y <- "John"
z <- 1:7
list(x, y, z)
# [[1]]
# [1] 42
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "John"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

This below seems to do what I want, but I feel I missed something crucial, as why isn't this the default behaviour?

```
namedlist <- function(...) {
  L <- list(...)
  names(L) <- unlist( lapply( as.list( match.call())[-1L],
                              as.character))
  return( L )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to answer your "why" question but it is what the default behavior of list is. By default R, creates an unnamed list if you don't create the names input explicitly.

So you can create a named list using

```
list(x = x, y = y, z = z)
```

Or `tibble` has `lst` function which behaves same as your `namedlist`

```
tibble::lst(x, y, z)
#$x
#[1] 42

#$y
#[1] "John"

#$z
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default R's lists are unnamed.

To create a named list, there's no need for your own custom function `namedlist()`.

You're getting confused between merely ***referencing the values*** of `x, y, z`:

```
l1 <- list(x, y, z)
```

vs actually ***declaring named elements*** in a list:

```
l1 <- list(x=42, y="John", z=1:7)
```

(or else using `setNames()` on an unnamed list).